# AWS application load balancer 404

Tags: amazon-web-services

I'm following tutorial to create an application load balancer and the listener path is as follow:

LB -> path -> server1
or   -> path -> server2

The problem:

I can get to server1 via the LB url ok but when I tried to go to server2 i received 404 page.

If i delete & reconfigure the LB & swap the server around then I can get to server2 but will get 404 if i tried to go to server1.

I can get to both server just fine directly.

Thanks for your help

---

[image: Screenshot1]

---

[image: Screenshot2]

---

[image: Screenshot3]

Comment: Post a screenshot of your ALB Target Group config showing the paths and targets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* you're getting 404 because when you access {YourALB}**/server1/something** the path is passed on to {IntASG}**/server1**/something instead of {IntASG}**/something**. If you can check the IntASG access logs you will probably see it there.

IIRC there is a way to remove the routing part of the path before forwarding it on to the backend. Check the ALB docs, it will be described there.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html#rule-condition-types

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I suspected so. Thanks for confirming that. Back to reading docs.

Comment: There is not a way to remove the path part of a path based listener rule, this must be done on the application server